# Unable to deploy java firebase function - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Has anyone had any success with deploy a Firebase server function written in Java? I can't seem to find any documentation, and can't seem to get this going!

Project and config: https://github.com/ajaygautam/useradmin-firebase

When I run `firebase deploy`

It fails with `No npm package found in functions source directory. Please run 'npm init' inside`

Why do I need an npm setup in a java only project!
How do I move forward?

Thanks in advance.

Ajay

## askfirebase

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase CLI can only deploy functions written in JavaScript or TypeScript.  In fact, there is no runtime for Java at all for Cloud Functions even outside of the Firebase ecosystem.

Comment: Crap! I think I mixed up functions and admin-sdk-functions :(

Answer (score 2):

Google now supports jvm runtime, you deploy using:

`gcloud functions deploy kotlin-hello-pubsub --entry-point functions.KotlinHelloPubSub --runtime java11 --trigger-topic my-topic --allow-unauthenticated --memory 512MB`

Refer:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/jvm-langs#kotlin_4